# Windows Phone 7 Volume Settings programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a way to programmatically change the sound settings of Windows Phone 7? Enable or disable sounds for Appointment and all other notifications? Also to change the global volume i.e.:Ring tone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no API to enable the tasks that you've mentioned. You can adjust the sound volume for the sounds within an application by using the XNA API's, but that is the extent of the control that is currently available.

Comment: Adding to Derek's correct response. It's possible to write that app as a homebrew app that changes the registry. Those type of apps won't be distributed through the marketplace though.

Comment: @Derek Lakin, Could you please provide link to official documentaions?

Answer (score 1):

You can control the volume of the media player and of a sound affect, but you don't have control over the master volume. Also note there is a bug in the sound drivers on some HTC devices that causes them to ignore the volume setting on sound affects.