# Is there a way to read current system volume setting on Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I know you can't *change* it, but I'd like to instrument the system volume setting inside my app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no API for getting or setting the system volume. You can set the volume of your own MediaElements, however, this is combined with the system volume to determine the overall playback volume.

See also:

[Windows Phone 7 Volume Settings programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040044/windows-phone-7-volume-settings-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the MediaElement.Volume property?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.volume(v=vs.95).aspx

I don't know the exact way to use it, but it seem like there is a possibility with this class.

Sorry if it doesn't help you.

Comment: No, this only set the volume of mediaElement ... it ranges between 0.0f and 1.0  (it represents a scale of the master volume).. 0.0f is silence and 1.0 = full current master volume