# getting Master audio volume

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio, volume

Is there any way to get the master volume in windows phone 7?

I found out that it is not possible to adjust the volume level.

But I want just to know if the master volume is muted or not

Comment: Please, don't repeate yourself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356889/audio-volume-in-wp7

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to read current system volume setting on Windows Phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914643/is-there-a-way-to-read-current-system-volume-setting-on-windows-phone)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Master Sound Volume in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534595/get-master-sound-volume-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, current API does not allow you to do it.

Comment: so there is no solution or work around to get the current status (mutes/ not mute)?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only thing you can do - is to remind user to check  the sound settings. But I think that it's not polite. If I've muted my phone - I want it to be muted.

Comment: can you provide me with a reference

Comment: What kind of reference do you need? this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402531(v=vs.92).aspx#appplat_overview_runtime ?